# Stop/Start multiple roles in Windows Failover Cluster Manager

Tags: windows, powershell-2.0

I am using below  script to stop/start single role in windows failover cluster.

How to modify this script to stop/start multiple roles? Becasue, this cluster contains around 15-20 roles

PS C:\Windows\system32> Stop-ClusterGroup "INSTALL"

PS C:\Windows\system32> Start-ClusterGroup "INSTALL" -Wait 0

Looking for powershell script that How to stop/start multiple roles in windows failover cluster manager?